# Do per-project preprocessor definitions override inherited values?

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I want to set `_WIN32_WINNT = 0x0601` (Windows 7) but am finding it still seems stuck on `0x0502` - some WinAPI functions are not available and intillisense shows the value as 0x502 after rebuilding.

My preprocessor definitions window looks like this:

[image]

We have a standard properties file used for all our projects and I don't want to modify that just for one module... would this cause a problem?

If I manually redefine the value in my StdAfx.h file, it seems to work but I'm a little wary of doing this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32_WINNT
    #undef _WIN32_WINNT
#endif
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x601
```

Comment: Defining a preprocessor symbol on the command line is identical to using the [#define Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593.aspx). A preprocessor symbol cannot be redefined (unless both definitions are lexically - or syntactically in case of Visual Studio - identical). I would expect that preprocessor symbol definitions on the command line follow the same rules. In other words: Your use of preprocessor definitions is undefined. If `_WIN32_WINNT` is not identical across all compilation units, don't add it to the common property sheet used for all compilation units.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to control which set of preprocessor definitions gets picked up first, you can take a look at property sheets (.props/.vsprops). You can specify the order of evaluation using this, so your overriding .props file can be used before the default props.

For example, I have a product that is meant to run on Windows XP as well, so the _WIN32_WINNT needs to be 0x0500. I added a props for my Vista++ projects that specifies _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0600. I mark that to evaluate before the default props file. This approach may also work in MFC projects that don't compile in VS 2013 unless the WINVER is >= 0x0501.

It isn't a perfect solution, but other than using undef and define, this is probably the best option.

Answer (score 0):

> Do per-project preprocessor definitions override inherited values?

No, they don't.

Visual Studio is misleading by naming them inherited, as if they can be overridden. What happens is that all your defines starting with `WIN32` are simply made into a list that gets passed to the compiler this way: 
`/DWIN32 /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 ... /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502 /D_MDCS /D_AFXDLL`. As you can see whatever you try to set for `_WIN32_WINNT` get's "inherited" anyways.
This is really dumb, they should have inverted the order or defines, this way inherited values would not override values that you set in your project.

One possible solution to avoid this bug is to uncheck the buggy "inheritance" and to manually place inherited values before your overrides:

```
_WINDOWS
%(PreprocessorDefinitions)
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
```

This is how it looks in my project:

[image]